# Builder pattern - borrowed value does not live long enough

Tags: rust

I'm trying to implement a simple builder but struggling with lifetimes. The following is giving `error: borrowed value does not live long enough`. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28469667/borrowed-value-does-not-live-long-enough-when-using-the-builder-pattern) seems similar. If I store `t` in a mutable variable and then call `s` and finalize it works, but I want to get the one liner to work. What am I doing wrong?

```
struct Type<'a> {
    s: &'a String,
}

struct TypeBuilder {
    s: String,
}

impl TypeBuilder {
    fn new() -> TypeBuilder {
        TypeBuilder { s: "".to_string() }
    }

    fn s(&mut self, s: String) -> &mut TypeBuilder {
        self.s = s;
        self
    }

    fn finalize(&self) -> Type {
        Type { s: &self.s }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let t = TypeBuilder::new()
                    .s("a".to_string())
                    .finalize();
    println!("string: {}", t.s);
}
```

Comment: I asked a concise Question for this common rust error `error[E0716]` [error E0716: temporary value dropped while borrowed (rust)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71626083/error-e0716-temporary-value-dropped-while-borrowed-rust). It links back to this Question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem is that you're creating `Type` with a string slice based on a `String` from `TypeBuilder`, but `TypeBuilder` instance created with `new()` is destroyed immediately in the same `let` statement, so if this was allowed, the string slice would became dangling. And that's why it works when you store `TypeBuilder` in a variable first.

The problem with your approach to the builder is that the builder is the owner of data for the value it builds: `Type` references the contents of `TypeBuilder`. This means that `Type` instances are always tied to `TypeBuilder` instances, and you just cannot create `Type` and drop `TypeBuilder`. However, this is really unnatural - builders are usually transient objects which are only necessary during construction.

Consequently, in order for the builder pattern to work correctly your `Type` must become the owner of the data:

```
struct Type {
    s: String,
}
```

Then the builder should be passed by value and then consumed by `finalize()`:

```
impl TypeBuilder {
    fn new() -> TypeBuilder {
        TypeBuilder { s: "".to_string() }
    }

    fn s(mut self, s: String) -> TypeBuilder {
        self.s = s;
        self
    }

    fn finalize(self) -> Type {
        Type { s: self.s }
    }
}
```

This way your building code should work exactly as it is.

Comment: Awesome, thank you. That's actually similar to what I started with, but I was having problems, I think because I was using ``&mut self`` in my modifier functions, instead of consuming with ``mut self``.

Comment: Do you know why they use ``&mut self`` [here](http://doc.rust-lang.org/1.0.0-beta/book/method-syntax.html#builder-pattern)?

Comment: The approach with `&mut self`/`&self` works there because the builder there only works with `Copy` data, and the structure built by the builder does not contain references into the builder. It won't work for `String`s and other kinds of owned non-copyable data.