# Values does not live long enough in constructor and setter in OOP Rust

Tags: oop, rust, lifetime

I have the following code:

```
//! # Messages

/// Represents a simple text message.
pub struct SimpleMessage<'a> {
    pub user: &'a str,
    pub content: &'a str,
}

impl<'a> SimpleMessage<'a> {

    /// Creates a new SimpleMessage.
    fn new_msg(u: &'a str, c: &'a str) -> SimpleMessage<'a> {
        SimpleMessage { user: u,
                        content: &c.to_string(), }
    }

    /// Sets a User in a Message.
    pub fn set_user(&mut self, u: User<'a>){
        self.user = &u;
    }
}
```

But `$ cargo run` returns:

```
error[E0597]: borrowed value does not live long enough
  --> src/messages.rs:34:35
   | 
34 |                         content: &c.to_string(), }
   |                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ temporary value does not live long enough
35 |     }
   |     - temporary value only lives until here
   |
note: borrowed value must be valid for the lifetime 'a as defined on the impl at 28:1...
   |
28 | impl<'a> SimpleMessage<'a> {
   | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

error[E0597]: `u` does not live long enough
   |
54 |         self.user = &u;
   |                      ^ borrowed value does not live long enough
55 |     }
   |     - borrowed value only lives until here
   |
note: borrowed value must be valid for the lifetime 'a as defined on the impl at 28:1...
  --> src/messages.rs:28:1
   |
28 | impl<'a> SimpleMessage<'a> {
   | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I've tried changing the borrowing format of the variables at the function signature and it's contents with no success, it doesn't seem as a borrowing issue, but I don't really understand it, as the lifetime `<'a>` defined at `pub struct SimpleMessage<'a>` clearly designates the longest lifetime to it's components, and the `impl<'a> SimpleMessage<'a>` uses the same lifetime.

What am I missing?

**Similar Question:**
[“borrowed value does not live long enough” when using the builder pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28469667/borrowed-value-does-not-live-long-enough-when-using-the-builder-pattern)
Doesn't really help resolve this issue.

Comment: Can you please try to create a MCVE, e.g. replace `User` by an other type (`&str` for example)

Comment: Why are you calling `to_string` at all? This will create an _owned_ string, which will not have the `'a` lifetime - it will only live as long as the `new_msg` function.

Comment: @PeterHall would it make sense calling 'to_owned' instead of 'to_string' or nothing at all?

Comment: `to_owned` on a `&str` is identical to `to_string`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`str.to_string()` will create an *owned* `String`, which will not live longer than the `new_msg` method, so you will not be able to pass a slice of it anywhere. Instead, just use the `&str` argument, since it is valid for the lifetime `'a`, which is what you need.

```
/// Creates a new SimpleMessage.
fn new_msg(u: &'a User, c: &'a str) -> SimpleMessage<'a> {
    SimpleMessage { user: u, content: c, }
}
```

The other method also has a problem. You are trying to give an owned `User`, but the `SimpleMessage` struct requires a reference. It should look like this:

```
/// Sets a User in a Message.
pub fn set_user(&mut self, u: &'a User<'a>){
    self.user = u;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `to_string` if you want to store a reference to a string. Also, `set_user` must also take a reference, not a value (because there's no field in the struct to store it):

```
pub struct User<'a> {
    pub data: &'a u8,
}

/// Represents a simple text message.
pub struct SimpleMessage<'a> {
    pub user: &'a User<'a>,
    pub content: &'a str,
}

impl<'a> SimpleMessage<'a> {
    fn new_msg(user: &'a User, content: &'a str) -> SimpleMessage<'a> {
        SimpleMessage { user, content }
    }

    pub fn set_user(&mut self, user: &'a User<'a>) {
        self.user = user;
    }
}

fn main() {
    let data1 = 1;
    let data2 = 2;
    let user1 = User { data: &data1 };
    let user2 = User { data: &data2 };
    let mut msg = SimpleMessage::new_msg(&user1, "test");
    msg.set_user(&user2);
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=bba43269e1513a94ede2ba59b520672a&version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015)

---

If you want to save strings that are created at runtime (for example, with `format!()` call) you may want to store a `String`:

```
pub struct SimpleMessage<'a> {
    pub user: &'a User<'a>,
    pub content: String,
}

. . . 

fn new_msg(user: &'a User, content: String) -> SimpleMessage<'a> {
    SimpleMessage { user, content }
}

. . . 

let mut msg = SimpleMessage::new_msg(&user1, format!("created at {}", "runtime"));
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=13d5979a39364c7db87fc6180d70839e&version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015)