# Why can't I call a method with a temporary value?

Tags: rust, lifetime, temporary

I can't call `Foo::new(words).split_first()` in the following code

```
fn main() {
    let words = "Sometimes think, the greatest sorrow than older";
/*
    let foo = Foo::new(words);
    let first = foo.split_first();
*/

    let first = Foo::new(words).split_first();

    println!("{}", first);
}

struct Foo<'a> {
    part: &'a str,
}

impl<'a> Foo<'a> {

    fn split_first(&'a self) -> &'a str {
        self.part.split(',').next().expect("Could not find a ','")
    }

    fn new(s: &'a str) -> Self {
        Foo { part: s }
    }
}
```

the compiler will give me an error message

```
error[E0716]: temporary value dropped while borrowed
  --> src/main.rs:8:17
   |
8  |     let first = Foo::new(words).split_first();
   |                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^              - temporary value is freed at the end of this statement
   |                 |
   |                 creates a temporary which is freed while still in use
9  | 
10 |     println!("{}", first);
   |                    ----- borrow later used here
   |
   = note: consider using a `let` binding to create a longer lived value
```

If I bind the value of `Foo::new(words)` first, then call the `split_first` method there is no problem.

These two methods of calling should intuitively be the same but are somehow different.

Comment: The compiler literally tells you what's wrong: `temporary value is freed at the end of this statement`, `creates a temporary which is freed while still in use` and `borrow later used here`. I think the error message is pretty clear. If not, please tell us, what you are you understanding.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["borrowed value does not live long enough" when using the builder pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28469667/borrowed-value-does-not-live-long-enough-when-using-the-builder-pattern)

Comment: I don't think that the duplicate applies, since here the temporary **could** be dropped without trouble if it wasn't prevented by a wrong explicit lifetime.

Answer (score 7):

**Short answer:** remove the `'a` lifetime for the `self` parameter of `split_first`: `fn split_first(&self) -> &'a str` ([playground](https://play.integer32.com/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2015&gist=722e82987ffd1b0d2a21acbcc40e2763)).

**Long answer:**

When you write this code:

```
struct Foo<'a> {
    part: &'a str,
}

impl<'a> Foo<'a> {
    fn new(s: &'a str) -> Self {
        Foo { part: s }
    }
}
```

You are telling the compiler that all `Foo` instances are related to some lifetime `'a` that must be equal to or shorter than the lifetime of the string passed as parameter to `Foo::new`. That lifetime `'a` *may* be different from the lifetime of each `Foo` instance. When you then write:

```
let words = "Sometimes think, the greatest sorrow than older";
Foo::new(words)
```

The compiler infers that the lifetime `'a` must be equal to or shorter than the lifetime of `words`. Barring any other constraints the compiler will use the lifetime of `words`, which is `'static` so it is valid for the full life of the program.

When you add your definition of `split_first`:

```
fn split_first(&'a self) -> &'a str
```

You are adding an extra constraint: you are saying that `'a` must also be equal to or shorter than the lifetime of `self`. The compiler will therefore take the shorter of the lifetime of `words` and the lifetime of the temporary `Foo` instance, which is the lifetime of the temporary. [@AndersKaseorg's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54230289/155423) explains why that doesn't work.

By removing the `'a` lifetime on the `self` parameter, I am decorrelating  `'a` from the lifetime of the temporary, so the compiler can again infer that `'a` is the lifetime of `words`, which is long enough for the program to work.

Comment: That’s a good point. I never checked that `split_first` _actually_ returns references into its input, merely that its type says it can. Fixing the type is a better solution.

Comment: Let's say I do make the adjustment that you suggest in your short answer, does the restructuring of the lifetimes actually change the assembly code, or are we just making compiler-enforceable commitments to the compiler regarding the lifetimes of certain references?

Comment: @ClarkMcCauley lifetimes have no effect on the generated assembly. They only exist so that the compiler (and developers) can know how a function or interface behaves without needing to look at the code on the other side of the interface.

Answer (score 6):

`Foo::new(words).split_first()` would be interpreted roughly as

```rs
let tmp = Foo::new(words);
let ret = tmp.split_first();
drop(tmp);
ret
```

If Rust allowed you to do this, the references in `ret` <s>would point</s> [edit: *would be allowed by the type of `split_first` to point**] into the now dropped value of `tmp`.  So it’s a good thing that Rust disallows this.  If you wrote the equivalent one-liner in C++, you’d silently get undefined behavior.

By writing the `let` binding yourself, you delay the drop until the end of the scope, thus extending the region where it’s safe to have these references.

For more details, see [temporary lifetimes](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/expressions.html#temporary-lifetimes) in the Rust Reference.

* Edit: As [pointed out by Jmb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54229893/why-cant-i-call-a-method-with-a-temporary-value/54231303#54231303), the real problem in this particular example is that the type

```rs
fn split_first(&'a self) -> &'a str
```

isn’t specific enough, and a better solution is to refine the type to:

```rs
fn split_first<'b>(&'b self) -> &'a str
```

which can be abbreviated:

```rs
fn split_first(&self) -> &'a str
```

This conveys the intended guarantee that the returned references do not point into the `Foo<'a>` (only into the string itself).

Comment: @AndersKaseorg I would like to read if  there is a reference or documentation for the roughly  interpretation that you mentioned?

Comment: @ÖmerErden Sure, I’ve added a link.

Comment: I still don't think think this is correct. Rust _does_ allow the example that you've said it disallows. Also, in C++ this should not be UB for exactly the same reason: because the reference is to `words` which _does_ live long enough.