# why do I need to use `let` binding

Tags: rust

While trying to print out my home directory I came across the following error:

```rust
fn main() {
    let home = home::home_dir().unwrap().to_str().unwrap();
    println!("home dir: {}", home);
}
```

```
error[E0716]: temporary value dropped while borrowed
 --> src/main.rs:3:16
  |
3 |     let home = home::home_dir().unwrap().to_str().unwrap();
  |                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^                  - temporary value is freed at the end of this statement
  |                |
  |                creates a temporary which is freed while still in use
4 |     println!("home dir: {}", home);
  |                              ---- borrow later used here
  |
  = note: consider using a `let` binding to create a longer lived value
```

But if I split the part underlined in the error message and put it in a separate variable it works:

```rust
fn main() {
    let home_buf = home::home_dir().unwrap();
    let home_str = home_buf.to_str().unwrap();
    println!("home dir: {}", home_str);
}
```

My question is what's the difference between the two examples?
(I'm using the [home crate](https://crates.io/crates/home) in my code)

Comment: What part of the compiler's error message is unclear?

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28469667

Comment: Side question: does the fact that `home` apparently means two different things in the original example also cause problems?  Both a crate name and a variable name it seems.

Comment: That's a good question. I thought the variable name would shadow the crate but I tried using `home::home_dir()` on the next line and it worked fine.

Comment: @KevinAnderson No problems there, Rust is able to disambiguate between the two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way to look at it is that your original code is roughly equivalent to:

```
fn main() {
    let home;
    {
        let tmp1: Option<PathBuf> = home::home_dir();
        let tmp2: PathBuf = tmp1.unwrap();
        let tmp3: Option<&str> = tmp2.to_str();
        home = tmp3.unwrap();
    }
    println!("home dir: {}", home);
}
```

In other words, all the temporary values created by an expression last as long as the expression, and no longer than that. Storing a *reference* that borrows from `tmp2` into `home` is not allowed because, the reference would then outlive the value it borrows from.

By introducing a variable to hold the `PathBuf`, you made it last longer than the expression, and the reference becomes valid.

Answer (score 3):

`home::home_dir().unwrap()` provides a `std::path::PathBuf`.
Invoking [`.to_str().unwrap()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/path/struct.PathBuf.html#method.to_str) provides a reference to something that is stored inside the preceding `PathBuf`.
Thus, for the reference to be valid, the `PathBuf` must exist (and Rust enforces that).

In your first expression, the `PathBuf` is a temporary that will be dropped straight away; the reference `home` would be dangling! (it's an error).

In your second example, the `home_buf` binding keeps the `PathBuf` alive, then the reference `home_str` can be used as long as `home_buf` exists.